# Top Italian Airports when Expecting Guests for a Holiday Wedding

Tags: italy, rome, sicily

We are trying to have our wedding in Italy (because it's so nice, sunny and Mediterranean) and planning for a handful guests to be flown in.

The guests are coming from various parts (Los Angeles, New York, Hong Kong, London) and we would like to make sure that they have a hassle-free time in Italy. Choosing a good airport with connection is the starting point for us.

What we would like to know from the users here is the recommendation on different airports. Do you guys know which airports would be ideal for us? Or at least, recommend some resource for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'll definitely prefer Milan (Malpensa) over Rome, especially in the high season. Immigration lines at Rome airport are atrocious.

Better yet, plan your routes to enter Schengen area outside Italy (stopover in Munchen, Warsaw and Zurich are nice in my experience; Frankfurt and Amsterdam too huge to be nice), then connect to Milan.

Most of other airports are either farily small or packed with tourists, I guess.

Comment: I am a bit surprised by your experience in Amsterdam. Schiphol is hugely efficient but not really huge. It's true that it now has even more passenger movements than Frankfurt but I am always surprised by how smoothly things go and how close together all the terminals are. I had worse experiences in Zurich for example.

Comment: @Relaxed yes it's better than Frankfurt, but still large and not so cozy.

Comment: Better than Frankfurt... and Zurich! Zurich might be a third of Schiphol's size on paper but it feels more crowded, has longer distance between terminal (there is even a people's mover), longer lines, etc.

Comment: @Relaxed maybe I was just lucky at Zurich, or maybe it was smaller several years back.